# Cannot assign middleware before routes definition

Tags: node.js, express

I need to assign to `app` instance of `express-js` several middlewares, so I did:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use((req, res) => { req.bot = 'just as test' });
```

then I've:

```
require('../routes/router')(app);
```

which contains:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

   app.get('/test', (req, res) => { res.redirect(process.env.APP_SITE); });
}
```

when I type: `http://localhost:5000/test` I get:

> empty response

but this happen only in the example above, if I move `app.use` after `require('../routes/router')(app)` all works well but I can't use the middleware.

Why happen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the next route handler in your middleware or it will stop there.

Try

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.bot = 'just as test'
  next()
})
```

This will continue the request to your actual handler `app.get('/test'...`

Read more at http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html